# Comparison between big-Ω and ω notations

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, big-o-notation

Example of function f(x) such that it is true that `f(x) = Ω(g(x))` but that it is not true that `f(x) = ω(g(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Pick $f(x) = g(x) = x$. Then $f(x) \in \Omega(g(x))$ and $f(x) \not \in \omega(g(x))$.

Comment: I think this is quite a good example! 
Just to emphasize, Ω is the upper bound, while  is the **tight** upper bound.

Comment: @shripalmehta: sorry, but you are wrong is several ways. An $\Omega$ bound *may* be tight, while an $\omega$ bound is not. Both are *lower* bounds.

Answer (score -2):

```
f(x) = Ω(g(x)) , f(x) = ω(g(x))
Ω(g(x)) = ω(g(x))
0 = (ω - Ω)(g(x))
```

We have a TRUE statement whenever the difference between small omega and big omega approaches zero.

Define indicator function: when big omega, then TRUE, else (small omega) -> FALSE.

Comment: Ω(x) is the upper bound, while ω(x) is the tight upper bound (i.e. the function yields a value near to, but never equal to the upper boundary).
These are 2 different things, you started off stating that they are the same. Hence, everything went down the wrong path.